# How to pick a table_name value from one table and delete records from the table_name table based on a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, parameter-passing

We have a table. Lets call it Table_A. 
Table_A holds bunch of table_names and numeric value associated to each table_name. Refer to the picture below

[image: Example]

Can someone help me write a query to:
Select table_names from TABLE_A one by one; go to that table, Check the Date_inserted of each record against NO_OF_DAYS in Table_A and if the record is older than NO_OF_DAYS in Table_A, then DELETE THAT RECORD from that specific table.

I'm guessing we have to create dynamic values for this query but I'm having a hard time.

So, in the above picture, the query should:

1. Select the first table_name (T_Table1) from Table_A
2. Go to that Table (T_Table1)
3. Check the date inserted of each record in (T_Table1) against the condition
4. If the condition (IF record was inserted prior to NO_OF_DAYS, which is 90 in this case THEN delete the record; ELSE move to next
   record)
5. Move on to the next table (T_Table2) in Table_A
6. Continue till all the table_names in Table_A have been executed

Comment: Yes, you're right, you're going to need to use Dynamic SQL. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Larnu, I've tried using the following query
SET SQL = 'DELETE 
[' + dbo + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] where [Date_inserted ] < '
      SET SQL = SQL + ' convert(varchar,  DATEADD(day, '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR, NO_OF_DAYS) + ',' + ''''
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 102)
        + '''' + '))'
      PRINT SQL
      EXEC (SQL)

Answer (score 0):

What you posted as your attempt (in a comment), quite simply isn't going to work. Let's actually format that first, shall we:

```
SET SQL = '
DELETE [' + dbo + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] 
where [Date_inserted ] < '
SET SQL = SQL + ' convert(varchar, DATEADD(day, ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, NO_OF_DAYS) + ',' + '''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 102) + '''' + '))'
PRINT SQL
EXEC (SQL)
```

Firstly, I actually have no idea what you're even trying to do here. You have things like `[' + dbo + ']`, which means that you're referencing the column `dbo`; as you're using a `SET`, then no column `dbo` can exist. Also, variables are prefixed with a `@` in SQL Server; you have none.

Anyway, the solution. Some might not like this one, as I'm using a `CURSOR`, rather than doing it all in one go. I, however, do have my reasons. A `CURSOR` isn't actually a "bad" thing, like many believe; the problem is that people constantly use them incorrectly. Using a `CURSOR` to loop through records and create a hierarchy for example is a terrible idea; there are far better dataset approaches.

So, what are my reasons? Firstly I can parametrise the dynamic SQL; this would be harder outside a `CURSOR` as I'd need to declare a different parameter for every `DELETE`. Also, with a `CURSOR`, if the `DELETE` fails on one table, it won't on the others; one long piece of dynamic SQL would mean if one of the transactions fail, they would all be rolled back. Also, depending on the size of the deletes, that could be a very big `DELETE`.

It's important, however, you understand what I've done here; if you don't that's a problem unto itself. What happens if you need to trouble shoot it in the future? SO isn't a website for support like that; you need to support your own code. If you can't, understand the code you're given don't use it or learn what it's doing first (or you're doing the wrong thing).

Note I use my own objects, in the absence of consumable sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE TableOfTables (TableName sysname,
                            NoOfDays int);
GO

INSERT INTO TableOfTables
VALUES ('T1',10),
       ('T2',15),
       ('T3',5);
GO


DECLARE Deletes CURSOR FOR
SELECT TableName, NoOfDays
FROM TableOfTables;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX), @TableName sysname, @Days int;

OPEN Deletes;

FETCH NEXT FROM Deletes
INTO @TableName, @Days;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SET @SQL = N'DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + NCHAR(10) +
               N'WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, InsertedDate, GETDATE()) >= @dDays;'
    PRINT @SQL; --Say hello to your best friend. o/
    --EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL, N'@dDays int', @dDays = @Days; --Uncomment to run

    FETCH NEXT FROM Deletes
    INTO @TableName, @Days;
END

CLOSE Deletes;
DEALLOCATE Deletes;    

GO
DROP TABLE TableOfTables;
GO
```